# How to get rid of border of segmented images after unpatchify the images

Tags: python, image, shapes, reshape, segment

[image]I was trying to patchify my images(Original image shape 1024,1024, 3 to shape 128,128,3) and then after doing some operations, I tried to unpatchify the image. But when unpatchify the image, the border of the patched images are visible in the unpatched images. Could anyone suggest how can I get rid of these borders in the unpatched image?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import cv2
import time
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
from PIL import Image
from patchify import patchify, unpatchify

SIZE = 1024

def process_img(img):
   img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
   img=cv2.resize(img,(SIZE,SIZE))
   img = img.astype('float32') / 255.0
   return img     

def plot_images(Noisy,Clean,Predicted):
   plt.figure(figsize=(20,20), dpi=200)
   plt.subplot(1,3,1)
   plt.title('Noisy_Image', color = 'green', fontsize = 20)
   plt.imshow(Noisy)
   plt.subplot(1,3,2)
   plt.title('OASIS_Image', color = 'black', fontsize = 20)
   plt.imshow(Clean)
   plt.subplot(1,3,3)
   plt.title('MOSAIC_Image ', color = 'Red', fontsize = 20)
   plt.imshow(Predicted)
   plt.show()    

def patches(img,patch_size):
   patches = patchify(img, (patch_size, patch_size, 3), 
             step=patch_size)
   return patches
  
def prediction(img,model):

   img_h, img_w,channel_count = img.shape
   patch_height, patch_width, step = 256, 256, 128
   img_patches = patches(img,128)
   rows = img_patches.shape[0]
   cols = img_patches.shape[1]
   fig, axs = plt.subplots(rows,cols,figsize=(20,10))
   for i in range(rows):
      for j in range(cols):
         axs[i][j].imshow(img_patches[i][j][0])
         axs[i][j].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
         axs[i][j].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
   nsy=[]
   for i in range(8):
      for j in range(8):
         nsy.append(img_patches[i][j][0])
   nsy = np.array(nsy)

   pred_img = model.predict(nsy)

   output_height = img_h - (img_h - patch_height) % step
   output_width = img_w - (img_w - patch_width) % step
   output_shape = (output_height, output_width, channel_count)
   pred_img = np.reshape(pred_img,(8,8,1,128,128,3))
   pred_img = unpatchify(pred_img, output_shape)

   return pred_img

def normalize(x):
"""
Normalize a list of sample image data in the range of 0 to 1

"""
   return np.array((x - np.min(x)) / (np.max(x) - np.min(x)))

with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):

#Choose image you want to test
   target_image = 'D:/OpenCV_Practice/RZ_images_noisy/IMG_23.jpg'
   oasis_image = 'D:/OpenCV_Practice/RZ_images_clean/IMG_23.jpg'
   save_result='D:/OpenCV_Practice/Save_Predicted/Predicted.jpg'
#save_result_1 = 'D:/OpenCV_Practice/Save_RZ/RZ_predicted.jpg'
   model_path = 'E:/YOLO/GAN/Code/Fragment_ep20_best.model'

#Load model
   model = keras.models.load_model(model_path)

#Load and pre-process target image
   noisy_img = process_img(cv2.imread('D:/OpenCV_Practice/RZ_images_noisy/IMG_23.jpg',1))
   clean_img = process_img(cv2.imread('D:/OpenCV_Practice/RZ_images_clean/IMG_23.jpg',1))

#Predict image with Autoencoder 
   start = time.time()
   p_img = prediction(noisy_img, model)
   predicted = normalize(p_img)

   end = time.time()


#Save result of prediction at full scale to disk
   matplotlib.image.imsave(save_result, predicted)

#Plot comparison
   plot_images(noisy_img, clean_img, predicted)
   

   print(f'Prediction completed in {end-start}s.')
```

Comment: Please add your Python code and a sample input image to your question. Make sure the resolution of the posted input image is 1024x1024. Please also make sure that the code is "executable", and reproducing the issue.

Comment: Thank you Rotem. I have added the code and image.

Comment: There is way too much code that is not relevant to patchify and unpatchify. There are also multiple images in multiple paths, that I don't have. Please take the tour of [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is an important part.